# Sleep only for once everytime action triggers in for loop

Tags: c#

```
for (int a = 0; a < Count; ++a)
{
    if (my if)
    {
        action;
        sleep;
    }
}
```

Here is my current code. When I do it, sleeps for every member of loop. But i want it to sleep only for once for whole loop. How can i do it?

Edit: I guess I wasn't very clear. I want all my Counts to do action in same time and sleep. The code above sleeps every time a Count is starting to do action.

Comment: add boolean variable, after first sleep then set it to true. sleep is allowed only if boolean false.

Comment: so if your predicate in your if is true you want to do... action, sleep, action action, action....? Just checking because this seems like an unlikely thing to want to do...

Comment: @Chris i want all my Counts to do action in same time then sleep.

Comment: I think OP means he wants to run action on a different thread (one thread per iteration).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this...

```
sleep;

for (int a = 0; a < Count; ++a)
{
    if (my if)
    {
        action;
    }
}
```

or

```
for (int a = 0; a < Count; ++a)
{
    if (a == 0)
    {
        sleep;
    }
    action;
}
```

Comment: This is not the same. The Op will always call action before doing any sleeping.

Comment: The sleep should be after action to match OP's original code.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isSleepDone = false;
for (int a = 0; a < Count; ++a)
{
  if (my if)
  {
    action;

    if(!isSleepDone)    
    {
      sleep;
      isSleepDone = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't like comparing a `bool` to `true` or `false`. I would change it to `if (!isSleepDone)`

Comment: isSleepDone is redundant, because you can just test for "a == 0".

Comment: There are tons of ways how to do it...:=)

Comment: Hello @Stanley thanks for code yet it's not what I was looking for. I noticed that I wasn't very clear at first because of my bad English. I edited the topic with most likely understandable information.

Comment: I see. Probably you need multithreading. You can start all action at the same time using multithreading. The right C# way is probably Parallel.Foreach

Answer (score 0):

A simple boolean:

```
bool slept = false;
for (int a = 0; a < Count; ++a)
{
    if (myif)
        {
            action;
            if (!slept)
            {
                sleep;
                slept = true;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: slept is redundant, because you can just test for "a == 0".

Comment: @Polyfun What if `myIf` is `false` for a == 0 ?

Comment: What if myif causes a BSOD?

Comment: @Polyfun: that isn't a very useful response... if `myif` is testing for `list[a].IsLoaded` or something then that is different from `a==0`. Why not stick to the code we have rather than making assumptions?

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
for (int a = 0; a < Count; ++a)
{
    if (my if)
    {
        action;
        if (a == 0)
        {
            sleep;
        }
    }
}
```